# How to batch Cassandra dsbulk loading version 1.7

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0, dsbulk

I'm trying to load a large CSV (30 GB) file into my cluster. I'm realizing that I might be overloading my Cassandra driver which is causing it to crash at some point during loading. I am getting a repeated message while it loads the data, until a certain point where it stops and I get an error that stops the process.

[image]

My current loading command is:
dsbulk load -url data.csv -k hotels -t reviews -delim '|' -header true -h '' -port 9042 -maxConcurrentQueries 128

Using -maxConcurrentQueries 128 did not change anything in terms of errors.

Any idea how I can modify my command to make it work?